# angular string changes not detected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The changes of a variable string not working

```
var angulargap = angular.module("angulargap", []);
angulargap.factory('cartService', function($rootScope,$http){    
    var fac ={
        message:"factory",
        getCart:function(call){
            $http.post("/rpc.php", {app:"get_cart",pag:"cart"})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                fac.setMessage("success");      
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });

        },
        setMessage:function(m){fac.message=m;} 
    }
    return fac; 
});
angulargap.controller("iridium", function ($scope,cartService){     
    cartService.getCart();  
    $scope.message=cartService.message;
});
```

Instead updating an array everything works
what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: can you try and explain your problem a bit more.. its hard to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you debugged it already with chrome? Maybe `fac.setMessage` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the string variable with an object

```
var angulargap = angular.module("angulargap", []);
angulargap.factory('cartService', function($rootScope,$http){    
    var fac ={
        messages:{cartnum:"0"},
        getCart:function(call){
            $http.post("/rpc.php", {app:"get_cart",pag:"cart"})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                fac.setCounter("num from server");      
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });

        },
        setCounter:function(m){fac.messages.cartnum=m;} 
    }
    return fac; 
});
angulargap.controller("iridium", function ($scope,cartService){     
    cartService.getCart();  
    $scope.messages=cartService.messages;
});
```

now everything works and I see the result on the frontend
Can someone explain to me why it does not work if I use a string variable?

i get it so:

```
{{messages.cartnum}}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
 setMessage:function(m){fac.message=m;}
```

with

```
 setMessage:function(m){message=m;}
```